# How to remove this "edit mode" shadow thing?

Tags: rendering, shadows

So I'm trying to render a character using cycles blender, I go to edit mode and subdivide a part and this glossy texture shows up when you render it, I'm trying to get a smooth texture.

[image]

Idk how to remove it, can anyone tell me how to smooth this thing up?

[image]

Comment: Upload your blend file so that others can see what you're doing. Use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/.

Comment: A file would be great but it would help even more if you [edit] the question and explain on which step - subdividing in Edit mode, assigning a texture and rendering - do you get unexpected behaviour and what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a subsurface modifier to the mesh worked for me.

Before:
[image: before]

After:
[image: after]